# How to set all donation to redirect users to another page if successful payment is made

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, contribution-page, redirect

I want to set all civicrm Thankyou page to redirect to another page in Drupal 7.50 site.

CiviCRM version is 4.6.8

Can I add a URL direct(In drupal) for the Thankyou page which has a dynamic URL.

Any suggestion on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by CiviCRM by default and i cant find any drupal modules which can do the redirect from the thank you page.

If you are a developer, you can do this using hook_civicrm_buildForm hook.

We have done something similar to redirect from thank you page using buildForm hook. I have packaged the hook in an extension. You can download the extension here - https://github.com/rajeshrhino/uk.co.vedaconsulting.module.contributionpagesredirect

Before installing the extension, you need to edit main PHP file (Line no.6 - https://github.com/rajeshrhino/uk.co.vedaconsulting.module.contributionpagesredirect/blob/master/contributionpagesredirect.php#L6) and change the redirect URL to the URL in your site.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, extension works fine for successful transaction. However I want to set the unsuccessful transaction to redirect to another page.
The url of the page for unsuccessful transaction is  something like www.example.com/civicrm/contribute/transact?_qf_Main_display=true&qfKey=.........................  For every transaction only the qfKey value keeps changing. Is there any method to make this dynamic page redirect to a static page in drupal?


Please suggest on this. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the thank you pages have the same url (from Drupal's point of view), using Drupal's redirect module https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this Fuzion [extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.frontendpageoptions) may help with what you require. "Options added are 1) ability to choose an alternate thank you page instead of standard CiviCRM landing page"

EDIT: this mostly provides a field for where to send users. If you want this for 'all' your contribution pages, then you would have to retro-fill those.